Open search with singe character is not returning back results
Have the following documents in opensearch:...
{
        "_index": "000-xxxxx
        "_score": 2,
        "_routing": "xxxxxxx",
        "_source": {
          "id": "512",
          "property": "abc x def",
          "active": true,
          
        }

When i tried to get the result back with single letter search , its not returning back results:
"query": {
"bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                
            
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "wildcard": {
                                "property.whitespace_analyzer": "x"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "wildcard": {
                                "property.autocomplete": "x"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

I have used below analyser for property key:
"whitespace_analyzer": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                    },
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                    },


could you please share your index mapping as well

I don't know what's your mapping. But if I read your your analyzer, maybe u should change from must to should query.
Try this :
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "property.whitespace_analyzer": "x"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "property.autocomplete": "x"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

